# Data.table: operation with group-shifted data

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the folowing `data.table`:

```
DT <- data.table(year    = c(2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013),
                 level   = c(137,137,137,136,136,136,135,135,135),
                 valueIn = c(13,30,56,11,25,60,8,27,51))
```

I would like have the following ouput:

```
DT <- data.table(year     = c(2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013),
                 level    = c(137,137,137,136,136,136,135,135,135),
                 valueIn  = c(13,30,56, 11,25,60, 8,27,51),
                 valueOut = c(12,27.5,58, 9.5,26,55.5, NA,NA,NA))
```

In other words, I want to calculate the operation `(valueIn[level] - valueIn[level-1]) / 2`, according to the `year`. For example, the first value is calculated like this: `(13+11)/2=12`.

For the moment, I do that with `for` loops, in which I create `data.table`'s subsets for each `level`:

```
levelDtList <- list()
levels <- sort(DT$level, decreasing = FALSE)
for (this.level in levels) {
  levelDt   <- DT[level == this.level]
  if (this.level == min(levels)) {
    valueOut <- NA
  } else {
    levelM1Data <- levelDtList[[this.level - 1]]
    valueOut <- (levelDt$valueIn + levelM1Data$valueIn) / 2
  }
  levelDt$valueOut <- valueOut
  levelDtList[[this.level]] <- levelDt
}
datatable <- rbindlist(levelDtList)
```

This is ugly and quite slow, so I am looking for a better, faster, `data.table`-based solution.

Comment: I think the `lag()` function is a possible solution here.

Comment: Or possibly even `data.table::shift()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `shift`-function with `type = 'lead'` to get the next value, sum and divide by two:

```
DT[, valueOut := (valueIn + shift(valueIn, type = 'lead'))/2, by = year]
```

you get:

```
   year level valueIn valueOut
1: 2011   137      13     12.0
2: 2012   137      30     27.5
3: 2013   137      56     58.0
4: 2011   136      11      9.5
5: 2012   136      25     26.0
6: 2013   136      60     55.5
7: 2011   135       8       NA
8: 2012   135      27       NA
9: 2013   135      51       NA
```

With all the parameters of the `shift`-function specified:

```
DT[, valueOut := (valueIn + shift(valueIn, n = 1L, fill = NA, type = 'lead'))/2, by = year]
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly the kind of solution I was looking for. I tried a bit to use `shift` without success, now I see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `shift` with `Reduce`

```
DT[, valueOut := Reduce(`+`, shift(valueIn, type = "lead", 0:1))/2, by = year]
DT
#   year level valueIn valueOut
#1: 2011   137      13     12.0
#2: 2012   137      30     27.5
#3: 2013   137      56     58.0
#4: 2011   136      11      9.5
#5: 2012   136      25     26.0
#6: 2013   136      60     55.5
#7: 2011   135       8       NA
#8: 2012   135      27       NA
#9: 2013   135      51       NA
```

It is more easier to generalize as `shift` can take a vector of 'n' values.

Answer (score 1):

If you:

- don't mind using dplyr
- the year is the thing that relates your items
- the structure shown is representative of reality

then this could work for you:

```
DT %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(valueOut = (valueIn + lead(valueIn)) / 2)
```